# Having Trouble With Passing Strings Through Intents

Tags: java, android

So I have two app pages. The app is supposed to pass the pickedTask through to the second page and then it is supposed to show up on the next page. What I am getting is on the second page's creation nothing the textView assigned to change goes to nothing instead of **fire**.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKuU2.jpg

First page:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent goodIntentions = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerList.class);
    goodIntentions.putExtra("pickedTask", "Fire");
}

public void goToTimerList(View view){
    Intent goodIntentions = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerList.class);
    startActivity(goodIntentions);
}
```

Second Page:

```
        TextView mahTextView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.cluel.oc.R.layout.activity_timer_list);
    mahTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taskText);

}

public void Test(View view){
    Intent goodIntentions = getIntent();
    String mahString = goodIntentions.getStringExtra("pickedTask");
    mahTextView.setText(mahString);
}
```

Comment: Are you really trying to use Intents to pass around data between multiple views in the same app? Intents are meant to pass data between multiple apps instead. If you have just one app that displays multiple views, you don't need to use Intents for that. But, in any case, your second view is not receiving any text because you are not putting any text in the Intent that you start. Your code is creating two separate Intent objects, one with text and one without, and is then starting the second Intent (the one without any text)

Comment: I'm trying to pass data through multiple activities.

Comment: I bought some lessons online and this is what they were saying to do. Is there a better way to do this? A link perhaps?

Comment: "Intents are meant to pass data between multiple apps instead." This is incorrect. Intents are also commonly used to pass data between two activities in the same app.

Comment: You should show the `class Whatever { ... }` around each code snippet to make it clear which code is in which class. Basically make it look exactly like a .java file in your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent goodIntentions = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerList.class);
    goodIntentions.putExtra("pickedTask", "Fire");
}

public void goToTimerList(View view){
    Intent goodIntentions = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerList.class);
    startActivity(goodIntentions);
}
```

You have created two different `Intent` objects. `onCreate()` creates an `Intent` sets the text but otherwise does nothing with it. `goToTimerList()` creates an `Intent` and immediately starts an activity with it but does not set any extras. Because you have declared each intent variable locally to each function, they are completely unrelated even though they have the same name. Since you do not need the `Intent` in `onCreate()` for anything, you should just put all of logic to start the second activity in `goToTimerList()` including setting the text in the Intent:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void goToTimerList(View view){
    Intent goodIntentions = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerList.class);
    goodIntentions.putExtra("pickedTask", "Fire");
    startActivity(goodIntentions);
}
```

I suggest that you learn about local variables and fields. These two topics will help you understand more about how we use variables in Java.